# Get date from chrome browser with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i want get a date of each post of web pages, when i display content of this instruction:

code:

```
dateShare = WebDriverWait(post, 100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//a[@class='oajrlxb2 g5ia77u1 qu0x051f esr5mh6w e9989ue4 r7d6kgcz rq0escxv nhd2j8a9 nc684nl6 p7hjln8o kvgmc6g5 cxmmr5t8 oygrvhab hcukyx3x jb3vyjys rz4wbd8a qt6c0cv9 a8nywdso i1ao9s8h esuyzwwr f1sip0of lzcic4wl gmql0nx0 gpro0wi8 b1v8xokw']")))
print("date :", BeautifulSoup(dateShare.get_attribute('innerHTML'), 'html.parser').text)
```

i get this result like : `oeSntpsrdoh800996h92tha15l07c1ic6t17h99 hi`

Answer (score -1):

Could you put the website or the html code? Because I don't understand very well.

Only I can tell you that When I get the text of element I use in Python .text. [Example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-text-of-a-tag-in-selenium-python/)